# too many arguments in if statement

Tags: bash, syntax-error

I am trying to execute the command

```
dirFiles=( * )
if [ ! -e $dirFiles ]; then
    echo "NO FILES HERE"
fi
```

However, bash is throwing the error:

```
bash: [: too many arguments
```

I'm not quite sure why this error is coming about, if anyone could shed some light on this it would be appreciated.

Comment: Wrong. You have too many arguments in your `[` command.

Comment: Actually that works for me, though it's an odd way to do it. After `dirFiles=( * )`, `dirFiles` is an array; if there are no files, it contains a single element, a literal `*`. `$dirFiles` expands to the first element of the array (you need `${dirFiles[*]}` or `${dirFiles[@]}` to get the whole array). If that doesn't exist, the directory is empty. I do get a syntax error if the first file in the current directory has a space in its name. Possibly older versions of bash behaved differently; what's your `$BASH_VERSION`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're doing it wrong in the first place.

```
shopt -s nullglob
if [ "${#dirFiles[@]}" -eq 0 ] ...
```

Comment: This only works if the nullglob shell option is set when `dirFiles=( * )` executes.

Comment: Would that be the reason  I am getting a size of 1 in the directory even if the directory is empty?

Comment: @GordonDavisson: Right, fixed.

Comment: @BobDunakey: Yes, because the array contains a single element, '*'.

Comment: Thanks guys, makes more sense to look at array size than the way I was trying to go about it.

Comment: @BobDunakey: Yes, but I'm still not sure why your method wasn't working.

Comment: How do I disable globing after I issue my if statement as it is making it so commands like `rm ./Chromosome/New/*` impossible to execute.

Comment: Wait, I found it `shopt -u nullglob`